# Matlab imline snapping

Tags: matlab, graph, matlab-figure

Is there a way to make the ends of a line created by `imline` snap to the nearest data point on a curve?

I'm trying to measure the slope between two points on a curve.  The `imline` is great, but the ends of the line created by it do not snap to data points on a curve.

I'm wondering if I can drag the line around while both ends of the line remained on the curve.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It can be done using the `'PositionConstraintFcn'` property of [`imline`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imline.html). Its value specifies a **function handle that is called whenever the line is dragged using the mouse**:

> `'PositionConstraintFcn'`: Function handle fcn that is called whenever the line is dragged using the mouse.
>
> Whenever the object is moved because
>       of a mouse drag, the constraint function is called using
>       the syntax: `constrained_position = fcn(new_position)` where `new_position` is of the form [...]

The form of `new_position` is a 2x2 matrix, where each row is an endpoint of the line; and columns represent *x* and *y* respectively.

So all you have to do is **specify a function that finds the closest point for each end and returns that constrained position**. This can be done in two steps:

1. Create a function to do the actual job, using as inputs the new position (`2`x`2` matrix) and the set of allowed positions (`N`x`2`, where `N` represents the number of points of the curve). The output is a `2`x`2` matrix with the constrained position.

   ```
   function constr_pos = imline_snap(new_pos, positions)
   [~, ind1] = min(sum(bsxfun(@minus, new_pos(1,:), positions).^2, 2));
   [~, ind2] = min(sum(bsxfun(@minus, new_pos(2,:), positions).^2, 2));
   constr_pos = [positions(ind1,:); positions(ind2,:)];
   ```

   Define this function in its own m-file (`imline_snap.m`) and place it where Matlab can find it, for example in the current folder.

   Here's how it works. The function receives the two points selected by the mouse (`new_pos`) and the set of points defining the curve (`positions`). It computes the distance from the first mouse point to each point in the curve (`sum(bsxfun(@minus, new_pos(1,:), positions).^2, 2)`), and gets the index of the point in the curve with minimum distance (`ind1`). The same is done for the second point (giving the index `ind2`). Finally, those indices are used for selecting the appropriate curve points and building the ouput (`constr_pos`).
2. The above `imline_snap` function needs to be particularized with the allowed positions corresponding to the points of the curve. This is necessary because the `PositionConstraintFcn` must accept only one input, namely the first input of `imline_snap`. This can be done via an anonymous function (see the example below, line `fcn = ...`); whose handle is then passed to `imline`.

Example code:

```
h = plot(0:.01:1, (0:.01:1).^2); %// example curve. Get a handle to it
a = gca; %// handle to current axes
X = get(h,'XData'); %// x values of points from the curve
Y = get(h,'YData'); %// y values of points from the curve
fcn = @(pos) imline_snap(pos, [X(:) Y(:)]); %// particularize function using curve points
imline(a, 'PositionConstraintFcn', fcn) %// create imline with that PositionConstraintFcn
```

It should be noted that the code snaps to **actual curve points**. It doesn't for example interpolate between curve points. That could be done modifying  the `imline_snap` function accordingly (but could result in sluggish movement if the number of operations is large).

Here's the above example at work (in Matlab R2010b). The righmost endpoint of the curve was dragged arbitrarily with the mouse, but it is seen to be snapped to the curve.

[image]

As a bonus, it would be easy to modify the function to **display the slope in the figure title**. Just add the following line at the end of the `imline_snap` function:

```
title(['Slope: ' num2str((constr_pos(2,2)-constr_pos(1,2))/(constr_pos(2,1)-constr_pos(1,1)))])
```

Example showing slope:

[image]

Comment: This is crazy!!!!!  I have no idea of how your "constr_pos = imline_snap(new_pos, positions)" works, but it does like a magic.  Two questions for you.  How do I accept your answer?  Two, I have another question about showing the slope as that's another problem I've been trying to solve.  How do I show my codes?  Thank you very much.

Comment: @Eric The function used `bsxfun`,  which is a very powerful function. I suggest you read on that. Then to see how the function works you can watch the intermediate results To accept an answer, click on the tick mark in the upper-left corner. For the question about the slope, since it seems to be a different matter, I suggest you post a new question (referring to this one if you need to). in the question you can post code. Just be sure to format it properly (there's a button for that)

Comment: OK.  I did look it up.  Binary Singleton....those two words immediately lost me LOL  I've already posted these questions beforehand.  Nobody was able to give me the answer like you did.  I'll post a new one with the codes this time.  Thank you very much.

Comment: @Eric I've added an explanation of that function in the answer. To see how `bsxfun` works, try a simple example: `bsxfun(@plus, (1:3).', 10:10:40)`. Here it is used for generating all "combinations" of inputs and summing them (`@plus`)