# Displaying the slope of a line created by imline in a text box

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

This post is a continuation of the thread: "Matlab imline snapping" which was resolved.  The below is the working code that snaps the imline object to a curve.

```
function calc_slope(handle,event)

axis_h   = findobj(gcf,'Type','axes');
obj_h    = get(axis_h,'Children');
obj_type = get(obj_h,'Type');
if ~iscell(obj_type),obj_type = cellstr(obj_type);end

for i=1:length(obj_type)
    if strcmpi(obj_type{i},'line'),data = obj_h(i);end
end
xdata  = get(data,'XData');
ydata  = get(data,'YData');

on = get(handle,'State');
if strcmpi(on,'on') || strcmpi(on,'off'),

    fcn_constr = @(pos) imline_snap(pos, [xdata(:) ydata(:)]); 

    xy = imline(axis_h, 'PositionConstraintFcn', fcn_constr);

    addNewPositionCallback(xy,@(pos) disp_slope(pos));     
end


function constr_pos = imline_snap(new_pos, positions)

[~, ind1] = min(sum(bsxfun(@minus, new_pos(1,:), positions).^2, 2));
[~, ind2] = min(sum(bsxfun(@minus, new_pos(2,:), positions).^2, 2));

constr_pos = [positions(ind1,:); positions(ind2,:)];


function disp_slope(pos)

delete(findobj(gca,'Type','text'));

text((pos(1)+pos(2))/2,(pos(3)+pos(4))/2,['\DeltaY/\DeltaX = ',num2str((pos(4)-pos(3))/(pos(2)-pos(1))),...
                '    [\DeltaX = ',num2str(pos(2)-pos(1)),', \DeltaY = ',num2str((pos(4)-pos(3))),']']);
```

Every time the toggle button on the toolbar of a figure is toggled (on and off), a new imline object is thrown in.  There are many figures with different parameters so that the data has to be extracted from the figure.  In a given figure, there can be multiple objects: imline objects, text, and/or line; thus, the first seven lines in the calc_slope function.

The imline objects snaps to the nearest data point of a curve and it's beautifully done by imline_snap function which is an answer by "Luis Mendo".  Thank you so much.  This has been a biggest headache.

The final problem is now to show the slope of an imline object in a text box (instead of the title or the floating box).  It's attempted in the disp_slope function (and it's miserable).

I'm doing "delete(findobj(gca,'Type','text'));" only because without something like that, as the imline object is moved around, it will leave millions of text boxes.  I only want to show one most current slope calculation.

There are multiple problems with "delete(findobj(gca,'Type','text'));".  If I stop moving the line around, it will nicely show the last slope calculation.  However, as soon as I throw in another imline object and move the new one around, the text box in the first imline object will get deleted and of course.

Another problem is that even if I delete the imline object, the associated text box will remain.

In summary,

1. I want to show the current calculated slope in a text box
2. I want the text box for each imline object to remain even if there are multiple imline objects.
3. Finally, I want the corresponding text box to disappear as well when a particular imline object is deleted.

Can this be done?  Help please.

Thanks,

Eric

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't create a new text object every time. Create one initially

```
ht = text(.45, .85, ''); %// modify coordinates to place it where you want
```

and then **update its content (`'String'` property)** when the `imline` changes. To do the updating, modify the `imline_snap` function to accept `ht` as a third input and add the following line at the end:

```
set(ht, 'String', ...
    num2str((constr_pos(2,2)-constr_pos(1,2))/(constr_pos(2,1)-constr_pos(1,1))));
```

So the function becomes

```
function constr_pos = imline_snap(new_pos, positions, ht)
[~, ind1] = min(sum(bsxfun(@minus, new_pos(1,:), positions).^2, 2));
[~, ind2] = min(sum(bsxfun(@minus, new_pos(2,:), positions).^2, 2));
constr_pos = [positions(ind1,:); positions(ind2,:)];
set(ht, 'String', ...
        num2str((constr_pos(2,2)-constr_pos(1,2))/(constr_pos(2,1)-constr_pos(1,1))));
```

Then, when defining `fcn_contr`, pass the reference `ht` to the text object:

```
fcn_constr = @(pos) imline_snap(pos, [xdata(:) ydata(:)], ht);
```

Here's an example, borrowing the curve from [my previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32468895/2586922):

```
h = plot(0:.01:1, (0:.01:1).^2); %// example curve. Get a handle to it
a = gca; %// handle to current axes
ht = text(.45, .85, ''); %// create text
xdata = get(h,'XData'); %// x values of points from the curve
ydata = get(h,'YData'); %// y values of points from the curve
fcn_constr = @(pos) imline_snap(pos, [xdata(:) ydata(:)], ht); %// particularize function
imline(a, 'PositionConstraintFcn', fcn_constr); %// create imline
```

[image]

---

You can also **update the text position (`'Position'` property)**. Just change the last statement of `imline_snap` to include that. For example:

```
set(ht, 'String', ...
        num2str((constr_pos(2,2)-constr_pos(1,2))/(constr_pos(2,1)-constr_pos(1,1))), ...
        'Position', ...
        mean(constr_pos) + [.03 -.03]); %// manually adjust offset if needed
```

The offset `[.03 -.03]` is intended to avoid the text overlapping with the line. You may need to change it. Also, it may help to create the text object with boldface. The line becomes

```
ht = text(.45, .85, '', 'Fontweight', 'bold'); %// create text, in boldface
```

Here's an example with text position updating:

[image]

---

To **delete the associated text object when you delete the `imline` object** you need and [event listener](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/event.listener.html). This is an object with three main properties: a cell array of source objects, an event, and a callback function. When the indicated event happens to one of the source objects the callback function of the event listener is executed.

To create an event listener for the `imline` object's deletion, use that object's [`addEventListener`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/handle.addlistener.html) method and specify the event name and callback function. The callback function is specified by means of a [function handle](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/function-handles.html), and it should expect two inputs, which correspond to the source object and the event (this is how the callback function will know "why" it's being called). Even if those inputs won't actually be used, the function needs to be defined that way.

In this case, the event we want to listen to is `ObjectBeingDestroyed`, the source object is the `imline` object, and the callback function is `delete(ht)` (to delete the text object). So, the code in the above example becomes

```
h = plot(0:.01:1, (0:.01:1).^2); %// example curve. Get a handle to it
a = gca; %// handle to current axes
ht = text(.45, .85, '', 'Fontweight', 'bold'); %// create text, in boldface
xdata = get(h,'XData'); %// x values of points from the curve
ydata = get(h,'YData'); %// y values of points from the curve
fcn_constr = @(pos) imline_snap(pos, [xdata(:) ydata(:)], ht); %// particularize function
hi = imline(a, 'PositionConstraintFcn', fcn_constr); %// create imline and get a handle
addlistener(hi, 'ObjectBeingDestroyed', @(obj,event) delete(ht))
```

where only the last two lines are new.

Now whenever the `imline` object is deleted the action `delete(ht)` will be performed, thus deleting the text object.

Comment: the reason why I'm creating the text box every time the imline is moved is because I want the text box to follow with the imline instead in a fixed position in a figure...

Comment: But that doesn't require deleting the object and creating a new one. Just update its `'position'` property. See edited answer (last part)

Comment: Luis, I don't know how to thank you and I really admire your knowledge in Matlab.  I wish somehow I can take lessons from you LOL  There is one last task.  It's to make the associated text box disappear when an imline object is deleted (right-click/delete).  Can this be done?

Comment: @Eric Thanks for your kind comments. Yes, it can be done, by means of an event listener. Plese see edited answer

Comment: I am a professional well-experienced engineer and am impressed by you as I am sometimes by tech fellows at work.  I've searched online last several weeks and saw many scripts that I tried to puzzle together to solve these issues.  In my book, there are two types of solutions: brute-forcing (or crude) and elegant.  Your solutions are absolutely elegant.  I wish I can help others like you did me.  What a great joy!  I really hope that somebody pays you for these helps big bucks.  If you live in Washington, I'll treat you a real good meal.  All my issues have been resolved.  Thank you so much.

Comment: @Eric I feel very honoured by your comments. Thank you very much! I started in StackOverflow the same way: looking for help (and always finding it!), and then I decided to participate giving back in the field I know best, which is Matlab. I live very far from Washington, but your offer almost feels like the real thing. Thanks again!

Comment: this code has been beautifully working.  A big thanks again.  There have been incidents that I'd like to show the slopes of multiple lines instead of just one.  imline_snap snaps to the nearest data point of a curve whose x and ydata are the inputs to it.  What can I do to select a particular line and send its x and ydata to imline_snap?  In other words, I want to be able to click a line (in plot editor, it will get highlighted) and send the line data of that line to imline_snap.

Comment: @Eric The line you last clicked on will be the current object. You can get access to that object via function `gco`. So, you can get its `x` and `y` values within `im_snap` as `get(gco, 'XData')` and `get(gco, 'YData')`

Comment: Yes, I figured that out little after I @-ed you, but I couldn't figure out how to undo it.  Your response confirms my answer.  So, I'm happy.  Thank you again for your help.